# is there any kind of error in my code as it is not giving correct output

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
typedef long long int ll;
void prime_sieve(vector<int> p, int n)
{
    //first mark all odd number's prime
    p[2] = 1;
    p[1] = p[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 3; i <= n; i += 2)
    {
        p[i] = 1;
    }
    //sieve
    for (ll i = 3; i <= n; i += 2)
    {
        //if the current number is not marked (it is prime)
        if (p[i] == 1)
        {
            //mark all the multiples of i as not prime
            for (ll j = i * i; j <= n; j = j + i)
            {
                p[j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    //special cases so e have to mention then individually
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> p(n + 1);
    prime_sieve(p, n + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (p[i] == 1)
            cout << i << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am unable to find why it is not giving any output. Any one up with the same issue??
My compiler is showing error somewhere in new_allocator.h file in this position

```
#endif
    ::operator delete(__p);
      }

      size_type
```

The error is exactly at that delete(__p). I am not understanding it why this error is happening

Comment: Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [more about C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a vector out of bounds error (and other errors)

In your function

```
void prime_sieve(vector<int> p, int n)
```

`n` is the size of the vector. Then you have this

```
for (int i = 3; i <= n; i += 2)
{
    p[i] = 1;
}
```

If `n` is odd, then `p[i]` is an out of bounds error when `i` equals `n`.

Same issue here

```
for (ll j = i * i; j <= n; j = j + i)
    p[j] = 0;
```

`p[j]` is out of bounds when `j` equals `n`.

You have other problems as well, for instance you are passing the vector by value, so the changes you are making to it in `prime_sieve`, will not be visible in `main`.

Finally since you can always get the size of a vector with `p.size()` you have to think about the purpose of passing a vector size as a separate argument. I guess this is code that originally used an array and you haven't rethought it properly now that its using a vector.

Comment: Out of bound error should not be there as the size of vector I have already defined as `n+1` But thanks as I had passed the vector by value here ,was the main problem. It is done now.

Comment: @Avinashkumar No you are wrong. You created the vector as n+1, but then you passed n+1 to the function. So `<=n` in your function is out of bounds because **n is the size of the vector in your function**. Passing the vector by value would not cause a crash. That crash is caused by the vector out of bounds.